# How to solve PyLint ‘import’ flaws on a conda environment?

Tags: conda, visual-studio-code, pylint, flask-login, pythonpath

PyLint seems to turn a blind eye to my conda environment, although it is on PYTHONPATH.

I have recently created this conda environment to get way from pip-conda issues as recommended by https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/

PYTHONPATH is: /Users/owner1/.conda/envs/env02/bin/python.

1. PyLint flags “unable to import flask_login” error with PYTHONPATH set for conda env. Flags by underlining it and as a problem on VS Code. flask_login is installed on my conda env and it executes.
2. On the other hand, “import numpy” does not flag on PyLint but it is not installed on my conda env and does not run.

conda-edge install pylint-flask did not solve it, same issues remain. It is not available on conda install. Installing from pip would go against Anaconda's recommendations (unless this is your last package, and you never know that during development).

Comment: I think you need to set the project interpreter. Open the command palette and choose "Select Python Interpreter" or something similar, then select the interpreter from this conda environment.

Comment: That is already in place using "Select Python Interpreter". The flaws are still there.

Comment: You might need to *Reload Window*, also from the command palette

Comment: Just tried that. The flaws are still there. Thanks anyway

Comment: Is Pylint also installed in the same environment?

Comment: Yes, both Pylint and Pylint-Flask

Comment: I am having the same issue! I have the feeling the linter looks at what is installed in the base env. That could be a reason, why numpy is not failing but more specific packages which you probably don't have in your base env do flag.

Comment: @Lena - I went back to a Homebrew installation and picked up numpy with a pip install. Not using conda anymore, okay for my flask app so far